# Is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to dowload a image in my web page with the xpath expression

Part of code

```
    with open('stiker.png', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class "_3IfUe"]/img[crossorigin = "anonymous"]').screenshot_as_png)
```

Part of page source i'm trying to dowload:

```
   <div class="_3IfUe">
       <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/9a74a410-721b-4e8e-80f0-42d18288f480" 
       alt="" draggable="true" class="gndfcl4n p357zi0d ppled2lx ac2vgrno gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 ln8gz9je b9fczbqn i0jNr" style="visibility: visible;">
   </div>
```

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class "_3IfUe"]/img[@crossorigin = "anonymous"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: I think you need an equal sign between `@class` and `"_3IfUe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) pointed out in his comment, you are missing a `=` between the `@class` and the value `"_3IfUe"` that you are trying to compare.

After fixing that, you need an `@` before the `crossorigin` attribute name. Otherwise, it thinks you are looking for an element with that name.

It should be:

```
//div[@class = "_3IfUe"]/img[@crossorigin = "anonymous"]
```